# Не переименовывается файл в Android 10

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Написал решение для переименования файлов, но в Android 10 ничего не происходит, хотя в 11 и выше переименовывается нормально.

```
public class PathDiv {
public static String dev(String path){
    return path.replaceAll("^(.*)/.*?$","$1");
}

public static void renameFilesInDir(String path, String dirIn, String ext) {

    File checkFile = new File(path);
        if (checkFile.isFile()) {
            try {
                checkFile.renameTo(new File(dirIn, ext));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Метод renameTo возвращает значение false

path: /storage/emulated/0/Music/04. Kasger - Highland.mp3 dirIn: /storage/emulated/0/Music ext: Highland.mp3

```
PathDiv.renameFilesInDir(songItem.realUri,PathDiv.dev(songItem.realUri),newName.toString())
```

Помогите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

стектрейс:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private fun updateOrRequestPermissions() {
    val hasReadPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    val hasWritePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    val minSdk29 = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q

    readPermissionGranted = hasReadPermission
    writePermissionGranted = hasWritePermission || minSdk29

    val permissionsToRequest = mutableListOf<String>()
    if (!writePermissionGranted) {
        permissionsToRequest.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    }
    if (!readPermissionGranted) {
        permissionsToRequest.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    }
    if (permissionsToRequest.isNotEmpty()) {
        permissionsLauncher.launch(permissionsToRequest.toTypedArray())
    }
}
```

Comment: Метод `renameTo` возвращает boolean-значение. Какое значение этот метод возвращает в вашем случае, true или false? Нет ли в логах ошибок? [Добавьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1482626/edit) эту информацию непосредственно в вопрос.

Comment: Метод renameTo возвращает значение false

Comment: Может лучше использовать метод `move` вместо `renameTo`? Тогда, в случае ошибки, можно узнать причину из выброшенного исключения, а не гадать почему вернулся false

Comment: Files.move(Paths.get(path), Paths.get(dirIn + "/" + ext));  Возникает ошибка: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /storage/emulated/0/Music/can.mp3 -> /storage/emulated/0/Music/ca1n.mp3 (Android 10)

Comment: @UserAndroidDeveloper, добавьте стектрейс целиком прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил к вопросу

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что у вашего приложения нет доступа к файлу.
На А11+ вы можете создавать файлы в стандартных директориях без каких либо привелегий, но чужие файлы удалять/изменять таким способом нельзя, кроме того если приложение удалить а потом установить снова, доступа к этим файлам уже не будет.
На А10 доступ к файлам вне собственных папок приложения возможен только с флагом в манифесте:

```xml
<manifest ... >
  <!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting
       Android 10. -->
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Кроме того на Андроид 10 и ниже для записи файлов требуется привилегия `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` - нужно не только объявить в манифесте, но и [запросить](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) в коде перед попыткой работы с файлом.

**UPD:** у вас не запрашивается привилегия записи на А10 и выше включительно, исправьте на А11:

```kotlin
    val minSdk30 = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R
    ...
    writePermissionGranted = hasWritePermission || minSdk30
```

Comment: Данный флаг находится в моем манифесте: android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: Разрешения: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Ну а в коде разрешения получены?

Comment: Да есть. Добавил код к вопросу